# RequestError: The "listener" argument must be of type function. Received an instance of Object (when using node mapbox sdk)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mapbox

I have been trying to use Mapbox as a map API, but I have a weird error as in the title when I try to make a request. Can someone help me find the problem, please?

When I consoled log geocoder it turned out that I have the newest version which is not supported in the documentation. For example, I don't have this `config` object as an argument. I have `request`. When I hover over the function it shows this ⬇️ but in the geocoding.js file is `config` object as an argument

```
GeocodeService.forwardGeocode(request: GeocodeRequest): MapiRequest<GeocodeResponse>
```

```js
import mbxClient from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk';
import mbxGeocoding from '@mapbox/mapbox-sdk/services/geocoding.js';


const mbxMainClient = mbxClient({ accessToken: process.env.MAPBOX_TOKEN });
const geocoder = mbxGeocoding(mbxMainClient);

geocoder
       .forwardGeocode({
          query: 'Paris, France',
          limit: 2
       })
       .send()
       .then((response) => {
          console.log(response.body)
       })
       .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

Comment: You may find it yourself looking at the [documentation](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-sdk-js#creating-and-sending-requests)... It looks like you are not passing the `accessToken` to the right instance.

Comment: yes now  did like in the documentation one time it worked... but I had after this then catch block old console.log, because at first I tried to do it with async/await.... and when I removed this old console.log it still shows this error

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette please see the newest edit. It's strange, because here like this and in the file ```config``` object (in the library)